# PHP cutting up a date to insert into fields

Tags: php

I have a field in my database called 'date_added' ... It is a varchar column ( i know varchar isnt right, but its the way it was built ) ... When i extract the value from the database it prints it as

```
dd-mm-yyyy
```

On the form where i extract it to, there are 8 small text fields that need to be filled with each of the values, so one text field will have the first d, the second field will have the second d, the third field will have the first m ... and so on.

How would i go about doing this?

Cheerss,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<?php

$date = "24-11-2010";
$cleanup_date = str_replace("-", "", $date);

?>
```

Then, on your form, you would use it like this:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[0]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[1]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[2]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[3]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[4]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[5]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[6]?>">
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $cleanup_date[7]?>">
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`explode`](http://www.php.net/explode) with [`list`](http://www.php.net/list)and explode it on the '-' into separate variables:

```
list($day, $mon, $year) = explode('-', $date);
```

Should get you what you want.

**Edit**

As pointed out, you wanted it in eight parts, to do this you can just reference the data like an array, IE: `$day[0]` `$day[1]` and it should work well.

Comment: that doesn't split it in 8 parts

Comment: I think this is better than the other answers, when you go to print out your value just use $day[0] on the first part and $day[1] on the second part, and so on. That would be very readable and obvious as to what you were doing.

Answer (score 1):

Use [str_replace](http://php.net/str_replace) and [str_split](http://php.net/str_split):

```
$string = str_split(str_replace('-', '', $date_string), 1);
```

The str_split bit is optional, since you can access each string character using array index notation ($arr[0]). (I like to do it anyway to avoid confusion, because when I see that syntax, I expect an array).

Then in your HTML, something like (the quick way):

```
<input type="text" name="d[]" value="<?php echo $string[0]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="d[]" value="<?php echo $string[1]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="m[]" value="<?php echo $string[2]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="m[]" value="<?php echo $string[3]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="y[]" value="<?php echo $string[4]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="y[]" value="<?php echo $string[5]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="y[]" value="<?php echo $string[6]; ?>"/>
<input type="text" name="y[]" value="<?php echo $string[7]; ?>"/>
```

And when you want to save it back:

```
$date_string = implode($_POST['d']).'-'.
               implode($_POST['m']).'-'.
               implode($_POST['y']);
```

Answer (score -1):

IMO, no need to use arrays. I would do something way much simpler like:

```
<?php
$date = '12-09-1985'; // your original date coming from the DB

echo $date{0}; //day 1
echo $date{1}; //day 2

echo $date{3}; //month 0
echo $date{4}; //month 9

echo $date{6}; //year 1
echo $date{7}; //year 9
echo $date{8}; //year 8
echo $date{9}; //year 5
?>
```

Obviously you will echo that in the your input field.

Comment: even though curly braces are valid to access specific char, it's better to be consistent with the rest of the world and treat string as character array and use square brackets

Comment: Who cares what does the rest of the world. The curly braces syntax is perfectly valid and is mentioned in the PHP manual. http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.substr